# SharedPrefrences delay before initializing - Flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm using Shared preferences to save the user's name and login state even after closing the app. the Shared Preference I used in main.dart is fine because I used it in the main function and made it async, but when I'm trying to use it in other classes, I see a dark red screen for less than a second before loading the page and it makes my app so ugly. what can I do to fix it?

Here's my code:

```
late bool _isEditingText;
TextEditingController _editingController = TextEditingController();
late String initialText ;
SharedPreferences? _prefs;
@override
void initState(){
  super.initState();
  initializePreference().whenComplete((){
    setState(() {});
  });
}


Future<void> initializePreference() async{
  _prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  String? name = _prefs?.getString('name');
  if (name == null) {
    _isEditingText = true;
    initialText = 'Enter ur name';
  } else {
    _isEditingText = false;
    initialText = name;
  }
}
```

**Update:**
sorry for not including my exact error... here it is :

`LateInitializationError: Field '_isEditingText@37486951' has not been initialized.`

Comment: didn't see any error in console log?

Comment: also can you include your widgets in this page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are performing setState before all widgets are get initialised. So for that you can update `initState` as below:

```
void initState(){
  super.initState();
  WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
    initializePreference().whenComplete((){
      setState(() {});
    });
   });
}
```

If it's not causing issue, than you have to show loading indicator. Like initially when there is no data indicator will be there and once you get data from SharedPreference in setState - you have to remove indicator and load your data.

You can use `CircularProgressIndicator` for that.

initialise your boolean variable,

```
var isDataLoad = false;
```

once you get data in whenComplete(), set it as true and based on this variable you can declare your widgets.

```
isDataLoad ? Container( // Your widgets where you use "initialText" ) : CircularProgressIndicator();
```

Comment: It produces the same results as my own code... but thanks anyway.

Comment: How can I impliment loading indicator here?

Comment: I have edit my answer, Please check